# Monty Hall lets make a deal in JAVA using simpler operators and functions

Tags: java, if-statement

So I've been working on this assignment for about 12 hours and have been unsuccessful in covering all the parameters. I was asked to make a program based off of Monty Hall "Lets make a deal" and asked to check each user input for validity up to the switching of doors;

[image]

I'm having the following issues:

- if the user wants to switch doors after a zonk is revealed they're taken back     to the main menu where they're asked to pick a door. then put in a continuous input loop
- if the user's input is invalid at the switch doors scenario then the same problem as above happens
- problem displaying the win percentage
- problem when wanting to play the game again

please help, somewhat of a beginner so criticism is more than welcomed on all parts of the code.

```
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO 'LETS MAKE A DEAL'");
    System.out.println("Please Enter 'A' to Play, 'B' To Watch, or 'Q' To Quit");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String choice = input.next();

    boolean done = false;   
    double wins = 0;
    double loses = 0;       
    double games = 0;

    while (!done)
    {

        if(choice.equals("A"))
        {   
            System.out.println("Please Choose a door:\n");
            System.out.println("[1] [2] [3]\n");
            System.out.println("Type '1', '2', or '3'");

            if(input.hasNextInt())
            {   
                int chosenDoor = input.nextInt();
                if(chosenDoor <= 3 && chosenDoor > 0)
                {

                    int prizeIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);      
                    int finChoice = 0;
                    int zonkIs = 0;


                        while (prizeIs == chosenDoor)
                        {
                            zonkIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                            while (zonkIs == prizeIs)
                            {
                                zonkIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (prizeIs == 1 && chosenDoor == 2)
                        {
                            zonkIs = 3; 
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 1 && chosenDoor == 3 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 2; 
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 2 && chosenDoor == 1 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 3;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 2 && chosenDoor == 3 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 1;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 3 && chosenDoor == 1 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 2;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 3 && chosenDoor == 2 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 1;
                        }

                        System.out.println("\nI Will Now Reveal A Zonk\n\nDoor [" + zonkIs + "]");
                        System.out.println("\nKnowing This, Would You Like To Switch Doors? ('Y' or 'N') ");

                        String decision = input.next();

                        if(decision.equals("Y"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Pick A New Door (Not The One With A Zonk)");
                            chosenDoor = input.nextInt();
                            finChoice = chosenDoor;
                            System.out.println("\nWell Then\n\nThe Moment You've Been Waiting For\n");
                            System.out.println("The Prize is in\n\nDoor [" + prizeIs + "]");
                            if (prizeIs == finChoice || prizeIs == chosenDoor)
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nCONGRATUALTIONS!!!\nYOU WON!!!!!");
                                wins++;
                                games++;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                System.out.println("\n..Sorry, You Lost.");
                                loses++;
                                games++;
                            }

                            System.out.println("\nWould You Like To Play Again? ('Y' or 'N')");
                            decision = input.next();

                            if(decision.equals("N"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nWell Thanks For Playing\nYour Win Percentage was ");
                                if(wins <= 0.0 || wins < loses)
                                {
                                    double percentage = 0;
                                    System.out.printf(percentage +"%");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    double percentage = (wins-loses)/games * 100;
                                    System.out.printf("%5.2f", percentage +"%");
                                }   
                                done = true;
                                input.close();
                            }
                            else if(decision.equals("Y"))
                            {

                                System.out.println("*******************************");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again ('Y' or 'N')");

                            }

                        }
                        else if(decision.equals("N"))
                        {
                            finChoice = chosenDoor;
                            System.out.println("\nWell Then\n\nThe Moment You've Been Waiting For\n");
                            System.out.println("The Prize is in\n\nDoor [" + prizeIs + "]");
                            if (prizeIs == finChoice || prizeIs == chosenDoor)
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nCONGRATUALTIONS!!!\nYOU WON!!!!!");
                                wins++;
                                games++;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                System.out.println("\n..Sorry, You Lost.");
                                loses++;
                                games++;
                            }

                            System.out.println("\nWould You Like To Play Again? ('Y' or 'N')");
                            decision = input.next();

                            if(decision.equals("N"))
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nWell Thanks For Playing\nYour Win Percentage was ");
                                if(wins <= 0.0 || wins < loses)
                                {
                                    double percentage = 0;
                                    System.out.printf(percentage +"%");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    double percentage = (wins-loses)/games * 100;
                                    System.out.printf("%5.2f", percentage +"%");
                                }   
                                done = true;
                                input.close();
                            }
                            else if(decision.equals("Y"))
                            {

                                System.out.println("*******************************");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again ('Y' or 'N')");

                            }

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again ('Y' or 'N')");

                        }


                    }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
                }

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
                    input.next();
                }
            }

            else if(choice.equals("B"))
            {

            }
            else if(choice.equals("Q"))
            {
                done = true;
                input.close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again..");
                choice = input.next();
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: haha corrected the title, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this part of the code makes no sense:

```
while (prizeIs == chosenDoor)
{
    zonkIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    while (zonkIs == prizeIs)
    {
        zonkIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    }
}
```

The outer while loop here, since you change neither `prizeIs` nor `chosenDoor` inside, is going to be an endless loop.

Also, there is no point in choosing zonks out of the *three* doors, because after we have a `prizeIs`, there are only two zonks, which are the other doors. It would be best to use collections or array shuffles, I suppose, but if you are not allowed, you could list the possibilities.

```
if ( prizeIs == chosenDoor ) { // Note it's an if, not a while.
    boolean chooseFirstZonk = Math.random() < 0.5; // 50% chance
    switch ( prizeIs ) {
        case 1:
            if ( chooseFirstZonk ) {
                 zonkIs = 2;
            } else {
                 zonkIs = 3;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if ( chooseFirstZonk ) {
                 zonkIs = 1;
            } else {
                 zonkIs = 3;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if ( chooseFirstZonk ) {
                 zonkIs = 1;
            } else {
                 zonkIs = 2;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Then this `if`:

```
if (prizeIs == 1 && chosenDoor == 2)
```

becomes an `else if` to the above `if`.

Next, you have a bit of a misunderstanding about the game. Now that the zonk has been revealed, there are only two doors that are covered. If the user chooses to switch, he is not supposed to select a new door out of three. One is known to be a zonk, and one is known to be his previous choice which he chose to abandon. So when a user wants to switch, you are supposed to simply change `chosenDoor` to the unrevealed door.

- If the original chosen door is the prize door, you are supposed to switch `chosenDoor` to the second zonk. So if prizeIs is 1, and so is `chosenDoor`, and `zonkIs` is 2, you change `chosenDoor = 3`. If `zonkIs` is 3, you do `chosenDoor = 2`.
- If the original chosen door is not the prize door, you are supposed to assign `chosenDoor = prizeIs` - as the user chose a zonk, and you revealed the other zonk, so the only one remaining is the prize door.

So no user input is required in this case.

So you will need to change that large `if-else`. If the user chose to switch, you do the calculation. This `if` has no `else`, as when the user didn't say yes, he means to keep his original choice. At this point, check if `chosenDoor == prizeIs`, and calculate the percentages.

**Calculations**

First, you only need to keep two variables. Like wins and losses, or wins and games, or losses and games. You can always calculate losses as games - wins.

So always do `games++`, don't do losses at all, and do `wins++` when the player wins.

Now calculating the success percentage does not require those `if`s. `wins` cannot be less than zero. it also can't be greatar than `games`.

But what is important is to remember that if you divide an integer by an integer, you are going to get integer division. That is, `5/10` gives you **zero**, not `0.5`, because it's not an integer.

So it's important to convert one of the numbers to double before you divide. One simple way to do this is to change the 100 to 100.0, and move it to the beginning:

```
double percentage = 100.0 * wins / games;
```

This way, `100.0 * wins` automatically converts the value of `wins` to `double`. Therefore, when the result of it is divided by `games`, the value of `games` is also converted to `double`, and there is no integer division.